# wordpress newsletter captcha include issue

Tags: wordpress, plugins, captcha, newsletter

I have tried many newsletter word press plugins, When I first installed the newsletter plugin every thing work fine but when I insert customize captcha code in it, It gives following error.

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'NEWSLETTER_INCLUDES_DIR' (T_STRING) in /home/hqdemo/public_html/korhani/blog/wp-content/plugins/newsletter/subscription/subscription.php on line 1
```

When I revert all the changes to its original state It always gives the same error until I re install the plugin. 
I have tried almost 4 newsletter plugins but the same issue occurs on every one, I don't know what is the issue I am stuck here,

I have clear my browser cache also but nothing works.

This is my capcha code that i integrate in the newsletter form.

```
<div>
        <?php
        $digit1 = mt_rand(1,20);
        $digit2 = mt_rand(1,20);

        if( mt_rand(0,1) === 1 ) {
            $math = "$digit1 + $digit2";
            $_SESSION['answer'] = $digit1 + $digit2;
        } else {
            $math = "$digit1 – $digit2";

            $_SESSION['answer'] = $digit1 - $digit2;
        }
        echo $math;
        ?>= <input name="answer" type="text" />
    </div>
```

If any body know what is the issue point me out please, or If there is any captcha plugin that works with newsletter plugin please give me the link.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Error is not related to each plugin because some specific plugin using this directory.
Please mention the plugin.

Comment: This is just for reference, each plugin gives errors of their own directory.

Comment: every plugin gives error for the include directory, so its for specific plugin and its just for reference to error, every plugin gives errors of their own include directory